Context item on custom button click on richtext field
I added a button option along with edithtml

on the click, I am calling and executing the powershell
item:executescript(id=$Target,script={ACD773A7-93DC-49A8-8497-73CEEC9C5A9E},scriptDb=master)

I am not able to get the context item inside the powershell script.
However, if I execute the powershell script on click on any button in ribbon, I do get the context item.
Any idea why it is happening? and how can i get the context or current item on button click of richtext field

Could you provide more details? What kind of button have you added?

Have you added a button like this and want to get a context item?


You can try something like this:
Step 1: Modify the Button Command to Pass the Item ID
When defining your button command, you need to pass the current item's ID as a parameter to the PowerShell script. You can do this by modifying the command configuration.
Step 2: Retrieve the Item ID in Your PowerShell Script
In your PowerShell script, retrieve the item ID from the parameters and then use that ID to get the context item.
Here’s an example PowerShell script that demonstrates how to do this:
powershell
Retrieve the item using the item ID passed as a parameter
$currentItem = Get-Item -Path "master:/sitecore/content//*[@@id='{0}' -f $itemid]"
